# How to call retrieve from PHP using dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler

Tags: php, xcode

Can I use dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler with my code below:

```
// to call data if there are comments

NSString *checkTitle = self.currentList.qasidaId;
NSLog(@"%@ the title: ", self.currentList.qasidaId);

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/MyWebSite/checkphp.php?title=%@", checkTitle];
NSData *data =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];


self.jasonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
self.listArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < self.jasonArray.count; i++) {
NSString *cUserName = [[self.jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"userName"];
NSString *cTitle = [[self.jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"title"];
NSString *cComments = [[self.jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"comments"];
NSString *cTimeC = [[self.jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"commentsTime"];
NSString *cDateC = [[self.jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"commentsDate"];
NSString *cUserNameArabicC = [[self.jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"commentsDate"];
NSString *cTheUserIdC = [[self.jasonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"theUserId"];


[self.listArray addObject:[[ListOfObjects alloc]initWithUserName:cUserName andTitle:cTitle andComments:cComments andtimeC:cTimeC andDateC:cDateC andUserNameArabicC:cUserNameArabicC andTheUserIdC:cTheUserIdC]];

}

[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I need to use dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler with my above code, What do I need to change?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `dataTaskWithURL` and put all of the parsing logic and table reloading logic inside the `completionHandler` block:

```
NSString *checkTitle = self.currentList.qasidaId;
NSLog(@"%@ the title: ", self.currentList.qasidaId);

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://MyWebSite/checkphp.php?title=%@", checkTitle];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!data) { 
        NSLog(@"connection error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSError *parseError;
    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&parseError];
    if (!json) {
        NSLog(@"JSON Parsing error: %@", parseError);
        NSLog(@"data = %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        return;
    }

    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < json.count; i++) {
        NSString *cUserName        = json[i][@"userName"];
        NSString *cTitle           = json[i][@"title"];
        NSString *cComments        = json[i][@"comments"];
        NSString *cTimeC           = json[i][@"commentsTime"];
        NSString *cDateC           = json[i][@"commentsDate"];
        NSString *cUserNameArabicC = json[i][@"commentsDate"];
        NSString *cTheUserIdC      = json[i][@"theUserId"];

        [results addObject:[[ListOfObjects alloc]initWithUserName:cUserName andTitle:cTitle andComments:cComments andtimeC:cTimeC andDateC:cDateC andUserNameArabicC:cUserNameArabicC andTheUserIdC:cTheUserIdC]];
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.listArray = results;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}];
[task resume];

// Just remember, by the time you get here, the above request is
// *not* done. That's why we do the `reloadData` inside the block
// above, and not here.
```

Note, the `completionHandler` block (a) runs asynchronously; and (b) runs on a background thread. That latter point is why I refrain from updating any class properties or updating the UI from that background thread, but rather manually call `dispatch_async` back to the main thread when we're done parsing, which (a) updates the `listArray` and (b) performs the `reloadData` of the `tableView`

Comment: But [NSArray *results] is Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSMutableArry from NSArray. addObject also not visibale

Comment: I think you missed an edit I did almost immediately after posting, making sure `results` was a `NSMutableArray`. But, frankly, you shouldn't get lost in the weeds here. The basic idea is to put everything inside the `completionHandler` of the `dataTaskWithURL` , making sure to dispatch the update of the app's model and UI back to the main queue.